# Laravel 8 : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-8

i have this problem in Laravel 8 on postman  :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sayara_wipou2021`.`post`, CONSTRAINT `post_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `post` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `price`, `category_id`) values (?, post700, description de post 700, 7800.00, 1))

I can not understand what is the problem on my code !
just i want to add Post with ForeignKey category_id

this is my Postcontroller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new post();
    $post->id             = $request->id             ;  
    $post->title          = $request->title          ;
    $post->description    = $request->description    ;
    $post->price          = $request->price          ;  
    $post->category_id      = $request->category_id  ;  
    if($post->save()){
        return new PostResource($post);
    }
   }
```

this my PostModel:

```
protected $fillable = 
[
    'id',
    'title',
    'description',
    'price'   , 
    'category_id',   
    'picture'
];
 public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class,'category_id');
}
```

this my postTable :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id', true)->unsigned();
        $table->String('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->decimal('price', 17)->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); }
```

this is CategoriesModel :

```
 protected $fillable = ['name','description','picture'];

public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: Your error is talking about `user_id`, not `category_id`. The migration you posted doesn't have `user_id`, was it added in a later migration? Either way, you either need to remove the `user_id` column from the `posts` table if you don't want it, or include `$post->user_id = ...;` and provide a valid `users.id` reference.

Comment: thank you bro it workes now

Comment: No problem, happy to help!